# PHP page redirect depending on jQuery selectmenu choice

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, redirect

I need to redirect my selectmenu options using PHP. Basically, I need to be able to choose a teacher in the selectmenu and when I submit the page, it redirects to that specific teachers page.

```
<?php
     ob_start();
     session_start();
     require_once 'dbconnect.php';

     if( !isset($_SESSION['client']) ) {
      header("Location: homepage_login.php");
      exit;
     }
     // select loggedin users detail
     $res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM clients WHERE client_id=".$_SESSION['client']);
     $userRow=mysql_fetch_array($res);


     if( isset($_POST['btn-nxt-page']) ) { 

      $client_student_id = $_POST['client_student_id'];
      $ss_name = $_POST['ss_name'];

      $client_student_id = strip_tags(trim($client_student_id));
      $ss_name = strip_tags(trim($ss_name));

      $count = mysql_num_rows($result); 

     if ($count) {

         $query = "INSERT INTO appointments(client_student_id,ss_name,) VALUES('$client_student_id','$ss_name')";
      $res = mysql_query($query);
     }

         function redirect($where){      
           header("Location: $where");
        }
        if ($_REQUEST['ss_name'] == 'John'){
            redirect('http://localhost/homepage_loggedin_book_john.php');
        }elseif($_REQUEST['ss_name'] == 'Smith'){
            redirect('http://localhost/homepage_loggedin_book_smith.php');
        }
     }
    ?>
```

This is my HTML, as you can see I have options and then in my PHP i try to redirect but it's not working...

```
<div class="form-group">
             <div class="input-group">
             <input type="text" name="client_student_id" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your Student ID" required />
                </div>
            </div>
            <br>
            <br>

       <label for="ss" id="menu">Select a teacher</label>
            <select name="ss_name" id="#menu">
               <option value="John">John</option>
               <option value="Smith">Smith</option>
               <option value="Greg">Greg</option>
               <option value="Jess">Jess</option>
            </select>
            <br>
            <br>

        <div class="form-group">
             <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-primary" name="btn-nxt-page">Next Page</button>
            </div>
```

Any help would be awesome. I just really need to get this working so I can move on.

If I'm not being specific enough:

I need the selectmenu options to be able to redirect to a new page when chosen and submitted.

Also, if anyone could help me to add in the values I'm entering through the selectmenu and the text box into my database that would be awesome!!

Comment: Everytime I see `mysql_*` and the word teacher somewhere in the same question, I die a little inside.. Please stop using it already. It's been deprecated for more than 2 years now!

Comment: What exactly is the problem? What is happening, or what not?

Comment: when i select an option from the menu and click submit, it doesn't redirect to the new PHP page which i create for the specific name. i just need it to redirect to a new page when i click submit based on the choice made in the menu

Comment: @Dekel The problem is that (s)he's downloaded some old code somewhere and is trying to get it to do what (s)he wants. Evidently show by the fact (s)he's missing the `header("Location: homepage_login.php");` on line 7 yet (s)he doesn't understand it should be the same at the `redirect()` parts..

Comment: @Isabella I strongly advise that you stop messing around with code that you do not understand. You can't dive into the ocean without getting your swimming certificate first. You'll simply drawn. That code is very insecure and will get you into serious trouble very fast. Put some efford into learning the basics and you'll be writing this kind of code yourself completely secure within no time at all :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the code below and get rid of the redirect function.

```
if ($_REQUEST['ss_name'] == 'John'){
    redirect('http://localhost/homepage_loggedin_book_john.php');
}elseif($_REQUEST['ss_name'] == 'Smith'){
    redirect('http://localhost/homepage_loggedin_book_smith.php');
}

if ($_REQUEST['ss_name'] == 'John') {
    header("Location: http://localhost/homepage_loggedin_book_john.php");
} else if ($_REQUEST['ss_name'] == 'Smith') {
    header("Location: http://localhost/homepage_loggedin_book_smith.php");
}
```

Try this and post any errors.

Comment: Thanks! But submit button isn't working... As in when I press it, nothing happens? My page still won't redirect

Comment: Do you have a form tag? Make sure there is <form action="" method="post"> tag closing after the <button type="submit" tag </form>